# Testing and mocking asynchronous code that uses async with statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-asyncio

I have a simple asynchronous functions that fetches JSON from the web:

```
async def fetch (session : aiohttp.ClientSession, url : str, pageSize : int = 100, pageNumber : int = 0):
    async with session.get(url, params={'pageSize' : f"{pageSize}", 'pageNumber' : f"{pageNumber}"}) as response:
        return await response.json()
```

How do I write unit tests for it? I am learning how to do that in Python currently and I have settled down on using `unittest` and `aiounittest` modules. The scaffolding that I use for testing is as follows:

```
class AsyncTest(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):
    async def test_fetch(self):
        mocked_session = ... #no idea how to create
        json = await fetch(mocked_session, "url_for_mock", 10, 0)
```

I think I would have to somehow mock the `session` argument using `unittest.Mock()` functionality to return some harcoded json data but I am a little lost on how to do this so it works inside `async with` statement. I have never used an unit testing library in Python and an example would be very helpful here. I am using Python 3.8 and `aiohttp` for networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to mock the asynchronous resource manager by implementing my own version of `__aenter__` magic method and using `AsyncMock` to mock relevant `async` methods. The proof of concept test that mocks network calls looks like follows:

```
class AsyncTest(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):
    async def test_fetch(self):

        request_mock = AsyncMock()
        request_mock.__aenter__.return_value = request_mock
        request_mock.json.return_value = { 'hello' : 'world'}

        session = Mock()
        session.get.return_value = request_mock

        json = await fetch(session, "url_for_mock", 10, 0)
```